# $G \le S_n$ G operates transitively on the group $X = \{(i,j)| i \ne j , 1 \le i , j \le n \}$ show that $G = S_n$

Tags: abstract-algebra, symmetric-groups

$G \le S_n$  G operates on the set $X = \{(i,j)| i \ne j , 1 \le i , j \le n \}$ by $\mu (i,j) = (\mu (i), \mu (j))$.

If $(12) \in G$ and G operates transitively on X (there exists only one orbit), show that $G = S_n$.

What I tried:

I know that (12)(23)..(n-1 n) are all in X.

If I can prove they are also in G I'm done. But I had trouble showing that.

I tried to use the orbit stabiliser theorem but also without success.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Do you know what happens to $(1 \, 2)$ if you conjugate it with a permutation $\tau$?

Answer (score 3):

Since $S_n$ is generated by its transpositions, it is enough to show that $G$ contains all transpositions. Now, if $\tau\in G$, then $$\tau(12)\tau^{-1}=(\tau(1),\tau(2)).$$ Since $G$ acts transitively on $X$, for any $(i,j)\in X$, we can find $\tau\in G$ such that $\tau(1,2)=(i,j)$. Then, $\tau(1)=i$ and $\tau(2)=j$. This means $$\tau(12)\tau^{-1}=(ij)\in G.$$ Since this can be done for any $i\neq j$, every transposition $(ij)\in G$. Hence, $G=S_n$.